# divide two variables in swift and display as percent

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, division

I would like to know if there was a way to set up a button to divide two variables and then display the answer as a percent to the nearest hundredth. I have looked on stack overflow but have not found anything.

Comment: What did you try? Can you please your code?

Comment: (a/b) * 100 will give you percentage.  (For 'b'  the value is 'a', for 100 how much?)

Comment: can I make the variable have two decimal places?

Comment: Do you have problem with math or UI? show what did you try

Answer (score 1):

```
var a : Double = 5.0
var b : Double = 10.0
var c = ceil((a/b)*100)
```

ceil(Double) gets the ceiling value of an Double variable.